# Mastodon.py what does register your app mean?

Tags: python, mastodon-py

In the [Mastodon.py documentation](https://mastodonpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), the first thing it says is to register your app. What does this mean?

I tried running the following block of code without the first one and it worked fine. So what does registering do? Why is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

looking up the work *register* in the documentation navigates us to the registration part within it:
https://mastodonpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#app-registration-and-user-authentication

I guess this would solve your problem